# Better way to create state transformation for adding set elements to Map[K, Set[V]]

Tags: scala, scalaz

I have `Map[K, Set[V]]` and I am using Scalaz Lenses and State to add elements to it.

So far, I see myself doing this repeatedly:

```
myMapLens.member(key) %= {
    case Some(vals) => Some(vals + newValue)
    case None       => Some(Set(newValue))
}
```

Is there a better way to do this using Scalaz ? Casting my value set into `Some(...)` every time seems wasteful.

Specifically, is there a way to compose Scalaz MapLens and SetLens to achieve this ?

Comment: Not an answer, but I assume you're aware of [`MultiMap`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.mutable.MultiMap) and `addBinding`?

Comment: @TravisBrown - `MultiMap` has the annoying feature that if you touch it with anything (e.g. `map`) it suddenly isn't a `MultiMap` any more.

Comment: I want to use an immutable Map here.

Comment: @DragisaKrsmanovic, oh, right—for some reason I thought there was an immutable version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write an adapter to "flatten" the `Option`:

```
import scalaz._, Scalaz._

def noneZero[A: Monoid]: Lens[Option[A], A] = Lens.lensg(_ => Some(_), _.orZero)
```

This is a little more generic than you need, but has the same behavior for your use case:

```
val myMapLens = Lens.lensId[Map[String, Set[Int]]]

val myLens = myMapLens.member("foo").andThen(noneZero).contains(1)
```

You could of course use any of the other methods on `SetLens`—`contains` just makes for a nice demonstration:

```
scala> myLens.get(Map("foo" -> Set(1)))
res0: Boolean = true

scala> myLens.get(Map("bar" -> Set(1)))
res1: Boolean = false

scala> myLens.set(Map("foo" -> Set(2)), true)
res2: Map[String,Set[Int]] = Map(foo -> Set(2, 1))

scala> myLens.set(Map("bar" -> Set(2)), true)
res3: Map[String,Set[Int]] = Map(bar -> Set(2), foo -> Set(1))

scala> myLens.set(Map("foo" -> Set(1)), false)
res4: Map[String,Set[Int]] = Map(foo -> Set())
```

The following is arguably a slightly more principled way to write the adapter:

```
def noneZero[A: Monoid: Equal]: Lens[Option[A], A] = Lens.lensg(
  _ => a => a.ifEmpty[Option[A]](none)(some(a)),
  _.orZero
)
```

This behaves the same *except* that unsetting the last value in a set removes it from the map:

```
scala> myLens.set(Map("foo" -> Set(1)), false)
res5: Map[String,Set[Int]] = Map()
```

This may not be what you want, though.

Answer (score 1):

Vanilla

```
myMap + (key -> myMap.get(key).fold(Set(newValue))(_ + newValue))
```

seems easier.

So does writing an extension method, and there it's worth a little extra work to avoid needless reconstruction of anything:

```
implicit class MapsToSetsCanAdd[K,V](map: Map[K, Set[V]]) {
  def setAdd(key: K, value: V) = map.get(key) match {
    case Some(set) => if (set contains value) map else map + (key -> (set + value))
    case None => map + (key -> Set(value))
  }
}
```

Now you can merrily `myMap setAdd (key, newValue)`.

Comment: I was hoping that there was some way to compose Scalaz MapLens and SetLens to achieve this. Perhaps Monocle has something ?